# decrease the days in python

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

```py
Year = eval(input("Year:"))

import time
import datetime
from datetime import datetime.timedelta
t1 = datetime.datetime(Year,12,31).strftime("%m%d.%w")
t2 = datetime.datetime(Year,12,31).strftime("%j")
t3 = datetime.datetime(Year,12,31).strftime("%d")
t4 = timedelta(days=-1)
t5 = t1 - t4
```

I'm not good at English.
I want to decrease the days and the first one is 1231 in any years.
how can I decrease the days by "for loop" , the first output is 1231 , the second one is 1230 ,and the third one is 1229 .....until 0101 ?

I do not really understand the meaning of "timedelta" and "datetime".But I can't pretty understand the information of the web on python official web.

Comment: Its nice to see code snippets can run inside questions in this site but looks like python is not yet supported

Comment: your code will work if you remove the strftime from t1, t2, t3 .. which returns string instead of datetime object, that is why u are unable to do the "-" operation between a string(t1) and a timedelta object (t4). and later you can run strftime on t5 `t5 = (t1 - t4).strftime("%m%d.%w")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
>>> import datetime
>>> def back_in_the_past(start_year):
...     start_date = datetime.datetime(start_year, 12, 31)
...     for i in range(0, 5):
...       new_date = start_date - datetime.timedelta(i)
...       print(new_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
... 
>>> back_in_the_past(2014)
2014-12-31
2014-12-30
2014-12-29
2014-12-28
2014-12-27
```

You just have to change "for i in range(0, 5):" to back in time for more days.

datetime.timedelta(i) apply a translation in time - the first argument is in days, so "i" is in days.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
import datetime

Year = 2014

begin = datetime.date(Year,01,01)
end = datetime.date(Year,12,31)

for d in range((end - begin).days + 1):
    print(end - datetime.timedelta(days=d))
```

Or did I misunderstand your question?